Call Fortran from C++, segmentation fault ( core' generado)
intento llamar una funcion desde Fortran hacia C++,
cuando defino n_points=10^6 no genera problema, pero con n_points= 10^8 aparece  Violación de segmento (`core' generado).
Aqui el codigo fortran pi_rand.f90
module monte_carlo_mod
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    contains
    function  monte_carlo_pi(n_points) result(pi_estimate) bind(c, name="monte_carlo_pi")
    integer :: n_points ! = 100000000
    integer :: i, inside_circle
    real :: x, y, pi_estimate, radius
    real :: rand
    integer :: seed
    seed = 12345
    inside_circle = 0
    call random_seed(seed)
    do i = 1, n_points
        call random_number(x)
        call random_number(y)
        x = 2.d0 * x - 1.d0
        y = 2.d0 * y - 1.d0
        if (x**2 + y**2 <= 1.d0) then
            inside_circle = inside_circle + 1
        end if
    end do
    pi_estimate = 4.d0 * real(inside_circle) / real(n_points)
    print *, 'Estimated value of Pi:', pi_estimate
    end function monte_carlo_pi
end module 

Aqui codigo en c++ main.cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
// Declarar la función Fortran que se va a utilizar
extern "C" {
    double monte_carlo_pi(int n_points);
}
int main() {
    int n_points = 100000000;
    double pi_estimate;
    // Llamar a la función Fortran
    pi_estimate = monte_carlo_pi(n_points);
    // Mostrar el resultado
//    std::cout << "Estimated value of Pi: " << pi_estimate << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Codigos para compilar que use :
gfortran -c pi_rand.f90
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o salida main.o pi_rand.o -lfortran
time ./salida .
Me da error
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
. Que hice mal ?

Ese problema siempre ocurre cuando lees una posición de memoria que no debes. Puedes depurar el código línea por línea para descubrir en cuál se produce el error?

Parece que el parámetro lo estás pasando por referencia en lugar de por valor. El módulo FORTRAN piensa que es un puntero y al intentar acceder a esa dirección el programa se cuelga.
Simplemente pasa el parámetro por valor

module monte_carlo_mod
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    contains
    function  monte_carlo_pi(n_points) result(pi_estimate) bind(c, name="monte_carlo_pi")
    integer, VALUE :: n_points
    integer        :: i, inside_circle
    real           :: x, y, radius
    REAL(C_DOUBLE) :: pi_estimate;
(...)

Échale un ojo a esto para más detalles

Esto es casi segura a un probable desbordamiento de pila porque n_points = 10^8 requiere mucha memoria en la pila para las variables x y y.
Posible solución:
Usa asignación dinámica de memoria en Fortran con arreglos allocatable para x y y:
real, allocatable :: x(:), y(:)
allocate(x(n_points), y(n_points))

Primero, aumenta el tamaño de la pila en tu entorno antes de ejecutar el programa:
ulimit -s unlimited

Cambialo asi:
module monte_carlo_mod
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    contains
    function monte_carlo_pi(n_points) result(pi_estimate) bind(c, name="monte_carlo_pi")
        integer(c_int), intent(in) :: n_points
        integer :: i, inside_circle
        real(8) :: pi_estimate
        real(8), allocatable :: x(:), y(:)
        integer :: seed
        
        seed = 12345
        inside_circle = 0
        
        ! Asignación dinámica de memoria
        allocate(x(n_points), y(n_points))

        call random_seed(seed)
        do i = 1, n_points
            call random_number(x(i))
            call random_number(y(i))
            x(i) = 2.d0 * x(i) - 1.d0
            y(i) = 2.d0 * y(i) - 1.d0
            if (x(i)**2 + y(i)**2 <= 1.d0) then
                inside_circle = inside_circle + 1
            end if
        end do
        pi_estimate = 4.d0 * real(inside_circle) / real(n_points)
        
        ! Liberar memoria
        deallocate(x, y)
        
        print *, 'Estimated value of Pi:', pi_estimate
    end function monte_carlo_pi
end module

Si no estás seguro de que el problema sea por el desbordamiento de pila, otra posible causa podría ser que la función Fortran está usando demasiados recursos de tiempo de ejecución para generar números aleatorios y realizar cálculos para un valor tan grande de n_points. Para descartar problemas de memoria, intenta las siguientes soluciones:
Revisa el límite de memoria: Verifica que tu sistema no esté limitando la cantidad de memoria disponible. Puedes hacerlo usando el comando ulimit -a y revisando los límites de memoria virtual y de pila.
Verifica el compilador: Asegúrate de que tanto gfortran como g++ estén correctamente configurados para manejar grandes volúmenes de datos.
Usa un depurador: Ejecuta el programa con gdb para obtener más detalles sobre la violación de segmento y verificar si ocurre por la asignación de memoria o algún otro problema:
gdb ./salida
Prueba con valores más pequeños: Intenta ejecutar con un valor más pequeño de n_points cercano a 10^8 y verifica si el problema persiste al incrementar progresivamente el valor.
Insisto que el problema es la memoria, pero si la situación aún persiste, sería recomendable revisar detalladamente la interacción entre C++ y Fortran para descartar otros posibles problemas.
Asegúrate de que los tipos de datos coincidan correctamente entre C++ y Fortran.
integer(c_int) :: n_points

Noté que en Fortran estás usando integer sin especificar su tipo explícito. En Fortran, integer puede tener un tamaño predeterminado que no siempre coincide con el tipo int en C++. Para evitar problemas de compatibilidad en la llamada entre C++ y Fortran, es mejor usar integer(c_int) en Fortran, lo cual asegura que el tamaño del entero sea compatible con C++, o en C++ sería mejor usar un tipo más adecuado para manejar números grandes de manera segura, como long long en C++:
long long n_points = 100000000;

Esto puede ser la causa del fallo, especialmente cuando se pasan valores grandes como n_points = 10^8.

Muchas gracias, pero no estoy seguro que este sea el caso.

Parece una respuesta generada por AI

Es que, la pila tiene un tamaño limitado y si uno intenta manejar grandes cantidades de datos localmente en la pila, como ocurre con los números aleatorios x y y generados 100 millones de veces, es posible que se exceda la capacidad de la pila, resultando en una violación de segmento, precisamente lo que dice el error. Ya que tienes el core, puedes usar gdb para analizarlo y ver exactamente dónde ocurre el error.

He reescrito la función, ahora tienes el código como lo pienso. ¡Pruébalo!
Espero que estés usando Linux, o al menos una computadora POSIX normal. Si tienes la desgracia de estar usando Windows, entonces necesitarías cambiar ambos programas para usar heap... pero eso es otro lío en el que espero no tengamos que entrar.
